# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript receives two but execute one script

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I´m trying to show two alerts on page_load, but ScriptManager just execute my first one.
I realy don´t know what to do, can someone help me?

Here is my test code. It´s located inside the Load method:

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(currentPage, typeof(string), "Script" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
     "alert('1!');", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(currentPage, typeof(string), "Script" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond,
     "alert('2!');", true);
```

Comment: The Key parameter should be Unique. By putting '"Script" + DateTime.Now.Millisecond' you might get the same name on both cases. In such case, the script in overwritten.

Comment: Or better yet, combine all your scripts into a single string and run one `RegisterStartupScript` only. Hint: You can use StringBuilder if building a somewhat complex script.

Comment: doing a merge was the way to go! thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're probably getting the same key for both registrations. Try this way:

```
Page currentPage = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(currentPage, typeof(string), 
    "Script" + Guid.NewGuid, "alert('1!');", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(currentPage, typeof(string), 
    "Script" + Guid.NewGuid, "alert('2!');", true);
```

Or merge both scripts into a single one and make just one registration.